# Make Command not working after build-essential installed

Tags: compiling, make

I'm new to Ubuntu. When I run the `make` command, I get this error:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no make ile found.  Stop.
```

I saw others recommended using

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

I did this and still get the same message. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: What did you expect `make` to do?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do? Are you trying to compile software from source code? If yes, then what software? Usually with GNU software you'll have to do `./configure` and then `make` in the directory that contains the sources. See if there's a README with the software that explains how to compile it.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there something else I'm missing?

This is because there is **no Makefile present** in the directory where you are running make command

Comment: If it helps at all, this was to download redshift. In the source package there were two files called "Makefile" one was a ".in"' and I don't remember what the other was. In the README file, it simply said to do the "./bootstrap" and then "./configure". I manged to do that and then is said to just run "make". Should those Makefiles be in some other format?

Comment: @CMcGoo You must be running make in some other directory .